# How to include some files (header files, vocabularies, source files) into my eclipse program into a project?

Tags: c++, eclipse, file, include

I am studying and there is actually a subject called "Informatic Internship". There, I have to program some problems and excercises. I have installed all programs, the compiler and the IDE Eclipse. 
I have followed my script instructions until my problem arrived.
Now, I have to include some files from my hard disk into the Eclipse project. In my instructions is written: "Create a empty project (+ steps how to).Now you can include the templates files. For this, you have to put the templates into the actual project on the left side in eclipse." And the last step is my problem. It isn't possible to include this. There is just a strikethrough circle. So, my question is how to include to continue with my university internship?
Thanks for your answers!

Comment: Can you be more explicit please. Already have created your project, how are you trying to put your files? If you can show some images or specific instructions that you doing more people can help you.

Comment: Seriously I would ask someone who can look over your shoulder while you are showing them what you are trying to do. Seems a much more efficient way to get help than asking here.